# Chaining and passing result of promise to a promise further down

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise, chaining

I am chaining a few requests that return promises. The first one is a login check on some site that returns some credentials back. Then I making a admin.auth().createUser() call. After I know that this createUser call succeeds and that I know the login check succeeded, I want to use these two objects returned from both promises to make a third request to store information in firebase realtime database. I just dont know how to pass both those results to the final promise. Here's some code.

```
login(siteUser, sitePass)
   .then(credentials => {
      return admin.auth().createUser({
         'email': email,
         'emailVerified': false,
         'password': password,
         'displayName': username
       })
    })
    .then(userData => {
       return writeUserData(userData, credentials); // I need to pass credentials here but I don't know how.
    })
    .then(() => res.status(200).send('success'))
    .catch(err => res.status(500).send(err));
```

I need to pass the result from the first promise to writeUserData after createUser() resolves.

Comment: what is `userRecord` in `writeUserData(userRecord, credentials)`? why is `userData` ignored? do you not need the result of `createUser`?

Comment: woops its supposed to be userData

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is functionally equal to your code, except it passes `credentials` on to where it's needed for `writeUserData`. Rather than a completely flat promise chain, you add a .then to `createUser` response to return `credentials` rather than the **unused** (in your code) response from `createUser`

```
login(siteUser, sitePass)
.then(credentials => 
    admin.auth().createUser({
        email, 
        emailVerified:false, 
        password, 
        displayName: username
    })
    .then(userData => credentials)
)
.then(credentials => writeUserData(userRecord, credentials))
.then(() => res.status(200).send('success'))
.catch(err => res.status(500).send(err));
```

If, however, you've made a mistake in your code and

```
.then(userData => {
   return writeUserData(userRecord, credentials); // I need to pass credentials here but I don't know how.
})
```

was supposed to be

```
.then(userData => {
   return writeUserData(userData, credentials); // I need to pass credentials here but I don't know how.
})
```

(i.e. userRecord should've been userData) - then you are not ignoring the response from `createUser` - this doesn't make the code much more complex at all

```
login(siteUser, sitePass)
.then(credentials => 
    admin.auth().createUser({
        email, 
        emailVerified:false, 
        password, 
        displayName: username
    })
    .then(userData => ({userData, credentials}))
)
.then(({userData, credentials}) => writeUserData(userData, credentials))
.then(() => res.status(200).send('success'))
.catch(err => res.status(500).send(err));
```

Comment: Thanks! and yea it was a typo

Comment: cool, so the last code block should work

Comment: This didnt work as is. I needed to add return before admin.auth. Like the solution by @shivam

Comment: in that case, you copied the code incorrectly, a return there would be a syntax error as I'm using the shorthand arrow function notation which has an implicit `return` - notice the total lack of `{` after `=>`

Comment: Oh I see it now. One more thing. how can I properly catch the error from the return admin.auth().createUser()? If i simply add a catch and try to do res.send(err), the outer then's get executed. How can I finish the call in the inner catch or pass the catch to the outer one?

Comment: If you want to have an inner catch and also pass to outer catch then you throw in the inner catch. But the outer catch should be called in case of any rejection as the code stands now

Comment: OH it works now. Thanks! Idk what I did but I was getting unhandled promise rejection when that promise rejected but now it works.

Answer (score 1):

The Promise.all solution by **Maaz** would also work, Unless you need something from the login request into the createUser request.If thats the case, then you could use the solution below.

```
login(siteUser, sitePass)
.then(credentials => {
  return admin.auth().createUser({
     'email': email,
     'emailVerified': false,
     'password': password,
     'displayName': username
   })
  .then(createUserRes => ({createUserRes, credentials})
})
.then(userData => {
    // You can now access both the createUserRes & credentials as
    // userData.credentials or userData.createUserRes
   return writeUserData(userRecord, credentials); // I need to pass credentials here but I don't know how.
})
.then(() => res.status(200).send('success'))
.catch(err => res.status(500).send(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. You need to use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```
const loginPromise = login(siteUser, sitePass);
const createUserPromise = admin.auth().createUser({
  'email': email,
  'emailVerified': false,
  'password': password,
  'displayName': username
})

Promise.all([loginPromise, createUserPromise]).then(result => {
    // Then use result array
    return writeUserData(result[1], result[0]);
  }).then(() => res.status(200).send('success'))
  .catch(err => res.status(500).send(err));
```

Comment: this would execute `login` and `createUser` essentially in parallel - which possibly could cause problems if you take those function names to mean what they do :p